# How to select parameters for ADAM gradient descent

Tags: optimization, convergence, gradient-descent, adam

I am using ADAM for performing gradient descent. I am having difficulty in setting the learning rate, $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$. Along with gradient descent, I am projecting the paramters on $L_1$ ball such that the parameters are sparse. Currently, learning rate = 0.2, $\beta_1$ = 0.99 and $\beta_2$ = 0.999, I am getting below graph for convergence[image]

When I change $\beta_1$ to 0.999, I get the below graph [image]

I am not quite understanding how changes in learning rate, $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ affects the convergence, how can I make my convergence smoother. Also, when I am trying to make the parameters sparse, I get very slow convergence rate. How does making final solution sparse impact the convergence rate? Should I use other gradient descent methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ are are the [forgetting parameters](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Stochastic_gradient_descent#/Adam) for the Adam optimizer. The lower the either one, the faster the running average is updated (and hence the faster previous gradients are forgotten). Increasing $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ would make the graph smoother (think running average over a longer period). *Decreasing* the learning rate should also make the graph smoother. The reason for the relative roughness of your graph is probably more due to the relatively high learning rate, rather than $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$.